# WSL: ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect to amqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:5672//: Socket closed

Tags: rabbitmq, celery, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I can't open the socket using celery and WSL.

See the following info:

- [ ]  output of `celery -A proj report`:

```
software -> celery:3.1.26.post2 (Cipater) kombu:3.0.37 py:3.6.7
            billiard:3.3.0.23 py-amqp:1.4.9
platform -> system:Linux arch:64bit, ELF imp:CPython
loader   -> celery.loaders.app.AppLoader
settings -> transport:pyamqp results:disabled
BROKER_URL: 'amqp://guest:********@localhost:5672//'
```

- [ ]contents of `pip freeze` in the issue.

I am using pipenv. Pipfile:

```
[[source]]
name = "pypi"
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true

[dev-packages]

[packages]
django = "*"
django-allauth = "*"
django-crispy-forms = "*"
django-debug-toolbar = "==1.10."
numpy = "==1.15.3"
colorama = "==0.4.0"
dateparser = "==0.7.0"
django-extensions = "*"
python-binance = "*"
misaka = "*"
django-celery = "*"
celery = "*"

[requires]
python_version = "3.6"
```

## Steps to Reproduce

I am in WSL:

1. sudo apt-get install rabbitmq-server
2. sudo service rabbitmq-server restart
3. chmod -R 777 ./     ## otherwise I don't have permissions

#### Other infos

tasks.py:

```
from celery import Celery

# app = Celery('tasks', broker='amqp://jm-user1:sample@localhost/jm-vhost')
# app = Celery('tasks', broker='amqp://guest@localhost//')
app = Celery('tasks', broker='pyamqp://guest@localhost//')

@app.task
def add(x, y):
    return x + y
```

rabbitmqctl status:

```
[{pid,1716},
 {running_applications,
     [{rabbit,"RabbitMQ","3.6.10"},
      {ranch,"Socket acceptor pool for TCP protocols.","1.3.0"},
      {ssl,"Erlang/OTP SSL application","8.2.3"},
      {public_key,"Public key infrastructure","1.5.2"},
      {asn1,"The Erlang ASN1 compiler version 5.0.4","5.0.4"},
      {rabbit_common,
          "Modules shared by rabbitmq-server and rabbitmq-erlang-client",
          "3.6.10"},
      {xmerl,"XML parser","1.3.16"},
      {crypto,"CRYPTO","4.2"},
      {os_mon,"CPO  CXC 138 46","2.4.4"},
      {compiler,"ERTS  CXC 138 10","7.1.4"},
      {mnesia,"MNESIA  CXC 138 12","4.15.3"},
      {syntax_tools,"Syntax tools","2.1.4"},
      {sasl,"SASL  CXC 138 11","3.1.1"},
      {stdlib,"ERTS  CXC 138 10","3.4.3"},
      {kernel,"ERTS  CXC 138 10","5.4.1"}]},
 {os,{unix,linux}},
 {erlang_version,
     "Erlang/OTP 20 [erts-9.2] [source] [64-bit] [smp:12:12] [ds:12:12:10] [async-threads:192] [kernel-poll:true]\n"},
 {memory,
     [{total,55943096},
      {connection_readers,0},
      {connection_writers,0},
      {connection_channels,0},
      {connection_other,0},
      {queue_procs,2744},
      {queue_slave_procs,0},
      {plugins,0},
      {other_proc,19080304},
      {mnesia,65712},
      {metrics,184888},
      {mgmt_db,0},
      {msg_index,42728},
      {other_ets,1769840},
      {binary,62120},
      {code,21390833},
      {atom,891849},
      {other_system,12634158}]},
 {alarms,[]},
 {listeners,[{clustering,25672,"::"},{amqp,5672,"::"}]},
 {vm_memory_high_watermark,0.4},
 {vm_memory_limit,6791299072},
 {disk_free_limit,50000000},
 {disk_free,100481589248},
 {file_descriptors,
     [{total_limit,924},{total_used,2},{sockets_limit,829},{sockets_used,0}]},
 {processes,[{limit,1048576},{used,165}]},
 {run_queue,0},
 {uptime,4073},
 {kernel,{net_ticktime,60}}]
```

### Output:

when run: `celery -A tasks worker --loglevel=info` I get the following output:

```
 -------------- celery@Alvaro-Laptop v3.1.26.post2 (Cipater)
---- **** -----
--- * ***  * -- Linux-4.4.0-17763-Microsoft-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-18.04-bionic
-- * - **** ---
- ** ---------- [config]
- ** ---------- .> app:         tasks:0x7fd7952bcf60
- ** ---------- .> transport:   amqp://guest:**@localhost:5672//
- ** ---------- .> results:     disabled://
- *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 12 (prefork)
-- ******* ----
--- ***** ----- [queues]
 -------------- .> celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery


[tasks]
  . tasks.add

[2019-01-23 08:38:30,538: ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect to amqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:5672//: Socket closed.
Trying again in 2.00 seconds...

[2019-01-23 08:38:32,543: ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect to amqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:5672//: Socket closed.
Trying again in 4.00 seconds...
```

How can I open the socket to allow the communications?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Check if rabbitmq is up and running. Enable management console:

```
sudo rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management
```

then visit `http://localhost:15672` using guest/guest as credentials. Look for Overview page>Ports and Contexts.

If AMQP is bound to IPv6 (::), then it might be the issue. Open rabbitmq server config:

```
sudo vi /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-env.conf
```

and comment out

```
# By default RabbitMQ will bind to all interfaces, on IPv4 and IPv6 if
# available. Set this if you only want to bind to one network interface or#
# address family.
NODE_IP_ADDRESS=127.0.0.1
```

then restart the service:

```
sudo service rabbitmq-server restart
```

and check the connectivity to RabbitMQ again

Comment: thank you. I confused rabbitmq mgmt port with the actual ampq broker :'(

Comment: I was getting `Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5672` on windows with wsl2, uncommenting `NODE_IP_ADDRESS=127.0.0.1` worked, thanks.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I install rabbitmq-server on WSL and cannot connect to the server, although I restart server many times. However, I can't find /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-env.conf, mentioned by your answer. Instead, I create a new file  /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-env.conf, add two entries in it: listeners.tcp.default = 5672
listeners.tcp.local = 127.0.0.1:5672, and the problem is solved.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to configure everything using Redis instead of Rabbitmq:

```
sudo apt-get install redis-server
sudo service redis-server restart
pip install celery
chmod -R 777 ./
```

Place on any folder you want to execute the worker the file tasks.py:

```
from celery import Celery

app = Celery('tasks', broker='redis://localhost:6379')

@app.task
def add(x, y):
    return x + y
```

Then execute the following:

```
celery -A tasks worker --loglevel=info
```

The socket is now open!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have not installed and started rabbitmq.  The easiest way I have found is with docker, but you can install it in WSL with `apt-get` if you are using ubuntu under WSL by following [these instructions](https://www.rabbitmq.com/install-debian.html).

Comment: As put in the question, when I run `rabbitmqctl status` it shows a good response of the server

Comment: It looks like it is listening on ipv6 :: not on ipv4 localhost.  Can you try configuring it for 127.0.0.1?

Comment: how can you change the configuration?

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem, when I was following "Django, Scheduled Tasks & Queues (Part 2)" article on Medium, I also had a running rabbitMQ server, but my CELERY_BROKER_URL in settings was `amqp://username:password@192.168.0.38//`, which turns out to be incorrect. I reconfigured my rabbitMQ server using this [instructions](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/brokers/rabbitmq.html). I hope it will help you too)